# Passing parent state to child and passing this same state back to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 react components X and Y. X holds state which is calculated through different types of logic and through user input. Users can click on a button in X which will unmount X and render Y. Now there also exists a button on Y which when clicked unmounts Y and renders X again, however X no longer has its state because it was lost when the component was unmounted when we first rendered Y. How can I ensure that X "holds" onto its state even when it gets unmounted?

I've tried passing X's state as a prop to Y, but I'm not sure if I can pass this prop on Y back to X when Y unmounts?

Comment: Move the state to the closest common ancestor (parent) of `X` and `Y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the state that needs to be accessed through both X and Y, initialize it in a *parent component* of both X and Y, then pass the state and its setters down to both. For example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [showY, setShowY] = useState(false);
  const [persistentXState, setPersistentXState] = useState('');
  return showY
    ? <Y {...{ setShowY }} />
    : <X {...{ setShowY, persistentXState, setPersistentXState }} />;
};
```

This way, X can use its persistentXState prop and call setPersistentXState, and it'll persist even after `setShowY` gets called to unmount X and show Y again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a classic case of [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). You absolutely can pass state up from Y using callbacks and setting it in the state of the parent. Then pass it to Y again.

There is another trick, but it keeps both in memory so might not be the best: you can `display: none` using CSS instead of unmounting, which means it's there but the user just can't see it.